# How to repeat a process in a while until enter is pressed?

Tags: c, while-loop

I need to repeat a process and I'm using a while. I need to do antoher process when enter key is pressed and I'm using if(getchar()). The problem is that the while "pauses" when it gets to the if because it's checking if getchar() it's true. I need to know how to keep looping the while whithout it stopping to check if there's an enter.
I'm making a game in which you have 1 minute to guess as much names as you can. So the purpose of the while() is to countdown from 60 to 0 seconds (clears the screen and prints the new second and the name you're actually guessing every second). So I want it to keep running the while() so the timer keeps running, but if enter is pressed it only changes the guessed name to a new name and the timer keeps running. (I don't know if I was clear but this is the idea)

```
//program in c

while(//specific condition)
{
  /*- here goes the code for a timer that every second it clears the
    - terminal and prints the next number (in seconds).
    -
    -
    -*/
  if(getchar()) //the current program stops here and keeps running the loop 
                //until enter is pressed
    {
      //second process
    }
}
```

I expect the while to keep looping until there's an enter. When that happens I want it to enter the if, exit the if and keep looping.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to disable line buffering?

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[100];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
{
        if (strlen(buffer) == 1)
        break;   

    if (sscanf(buffer, "%f", &f) == 1)
    {
        total += f;
        printf("Enter another number: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `if(getchar()=='\n')`
so the program runs until an enter key is pressed

because buffer value of '\n' will be present and it'll alter the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

if you have `conio.h` available in your environment you can use `kbhit`

```
while(//specific condition)
{
  /*--process to do
    -
    -
    -
    -*/
  if(kbhit()) 
  {
      if (getchar() == 0x0d)
      { 
          break;
      }
  }
  //second process
}
```

In this loop, the second process will run without checking the enter key and only exit if enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a;
printf("Enter charecter or press enter to exit:");
scanf("%c",&a);
while(1)
{
    //process 1 loop
    if (a == '\n')
    {
        // process 2 here, if process two has loop make it's own loop here
        printf("we are in process 2\n");
        break;
    }
    getchar();
    printf("Enter charecter or press enter to exit:");
    scanf("%c",&a);
}
```

You did't give enough code to understand what input stream you are working with but something like this will do it, if it's file stream  or string do it accordingly by replacing scanf with fgets, or file stream inputs like fscanf or fread.